# How to find signal values after an instruction is executed in a single-cycle 32-bit MIPS processor?

Tags: mips, cpu, cpu-architecture

> Consider the following datapath for a single-cycle 32-bit MIPS
> processor.
>
> [image: Datapath for a single-cycle 32-bit MIPS processor]
>
> Suppose the lw instruction is executing in the following program:
>
> ```
> lui $t2,0x3f 
> ori $t2,$t2,0x11 
> lw $t8,4($t2)
> ```
>
> Instruction `lui` is located at address `0x40004044`. What are then the
> signal values for A, B, C, D, and E when the `lw` instruction is
> executed? For each signal, answer with either an integer number or
> write unknown for a signal value where it is not possible to determine
> an exact value with the given information.

How can I solve this problem? I have been given the answers but I have no idea how to do the actual problem-solving to get to these answers:

> The signal values are
>
> A = 24
> B = 0x003f0011
> C = unknown
> D = 0x40004060
> E = 0x4000404C

Comment: This is a computer hardware / electrical engineering question, not a computer programming question.

Comment: For `E` and `D`, those are based on the program-counter.  It's not a `b` or `j` instruction so D won't get muxed into the new program-counter, but it's still calculated as if it were, so that's where `D` comes from.  `E` is just the address of the `lw`, which starts 8 bytes after the `lui`.  (It's probably also being asked for so when they mark your answers, they can give you full marks for the tricky part of `D` if it's consistent with what you thought the inputs were from `E` even if that's wrong.)

Comment: `A` is the register-number of the load's destination, `$t8`.  It's the input to the write-address of the register file, and a sane MIPS just uses the 5-bit field from the machine code directly. 

`B` is the register value input to the `lw`'s  addressing mode, the non-immediate input to the ALU.  This is the constant constructed by the `lui`/`ori` (aka `li`).

`C` is the load result which depends on memory, whose contents we haven't been told.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Designing CPUs is arguably a kind of programming, and understanding CPU internals is relevant for writing efficient code for them. Student questions like this are baby steps toward learning those things.  I don't think we need to close questions like this *just* because of the subject, and this one is at least short and simple enough to be an ok fit for SO.  It's almost a homework question / no-attempt, but being asked to *explain* known answers and how to find them seems like an important difference from the usual questions just wanting someone to do their homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since this is a single cycle processor, the fact that there are instructions preceding the `lw` of interest, affects only the values in registers (including the PC) but not the control signals when the `lw` executes.

If the `lui` instruction is stored at `0x40004044` then the `ori` at `0x40004048` and the `lw` at `0x4000404C`.  Thus, when the `lw` is executing, the current PC value is `0x4000404C`.

So, let's start with `E`, which a PC value: `0x4000404C`, the location of the `lw` instruction.  You can see that this line comes out of the PC register, and goes into the Instruction Memory, which is the fetch for the `lw` instruction bits.  This PC value also goes to the increment circuit, that adds 4 to the PC value for sequential execution of the next following instruction.

Next, `A` is the register number of the target of the `lw` instruction.  How do we know this?  It is a matter of [instruction decoding](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf).  The `lw` instruction has the I-Type format.  This means that the `rs` and `rt` fields are relevant.  It performs `R[rt] = M[R[rs]+SignExtImm]`.  The `rs` field occupies bits 25:21 and the `rt` field occupies bits 20:16.  Thus, in `lw $t8,4($t2)`, the `$t8` is `rt` and while from friendly name of `$t8` we can know the actual register number value of `$24`, so 24 base ten (i.e. 24<sub>10</sub>), by simply looking that up in the Register Name table.

The `B` value is the contents of the register whose number is known as source register `A1`, bits 25:21 aka `rs`, here `$t2`.   This value, the contents of register `$t2`, is understood by following the execution of the prior 2 instructions, which form a 32-bit address into `$t2`, namely `0x3f0011`.

`C` is the output of the data memory fetch operation.  It is the value of the memory location `0x3f0015` (from `0x3f0011` + 4 as per the addressing mode).  Since this is an odd address, it will most likely fault rather than producing some value.  If it did not fault, then to determine the value you would have to be given the values stored in the 4 memory locations starting at `0x3f0015`.

`D` is the computation of the branch target as if the instruction were a branch — however it is not a branch, but non-the-less, the hardware will compute the branch target address only to throw that away.  Hardware works like that in many cases: compute something that we don't necessarily know is relevant, though the computation is done in parallel and just in case, rather than waiting to compute this only when it is truly known whether the value is relevant or not.

This value is simply (4 << 2), where the 4 comes from the 4 in `lw $t8, 4($t2)`, plus the PC value/location of the `lw` (plus 4 since the other input is post PC increment of 4).  So, `0x0400404c` + 4 + (4<<2) = `0x04004060`.

Comment: An easier way to figure out that A is the register-number for `$t8` is to look at where it's used: it's the A3 input to the register file, for the write port.  `lw` writes one register, this must be it.  You don't need to trace through the decoding if you can safely assume that is uses the 5-bit field from the machine code unchanged.  (I guess a real MIPS might perhaps have a NOT as an amplifier for a long wire somewhere?  And/or perhaps not use all 5 bits in the same order, actual reg numbers don't matter as long as the pattern for `$0` is still easy to special-case.)

Comment: A shortcut for identifying the `B` value is that it's the non-immediate input to the ALU, which does the address math for the `4($t2)` addressing mode.  It came straight from the register file so it's the register value, the other input must be the immediate `4`.